# XPM icon is appearing on LIVE website DXA 2.0

Tags: web8, dxa, experience-manager, web8.5, dxa-2.0

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 2.0 Java. We have found that on LIVE website XPM icon is appearing although there is no preview capability defined for live discovery service.

We have tried `Java -jar discovery-registration.jar forceSync` and also `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` but it did not fix the issue

[image]

Answer (score 2):

XPM icon will appear on page if you have XPM javascript reference in page source. Double check your page view and check if you are adding this manually.

Comment: The javascript was condition but we did not make XPM button condition thats why it was showing after making XPM button conditional issue get resolved                                                   `<xpm:if-enabled>
 <xpm:button region="${region}"/>
</xpm:if-enabled>`

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure you have the conditional check in your layout. in .Net, it is `WebRequestContext.IsPreview` check.
2. Ensure, in your Active site, in `_all.json` file, "staging" attribute value is "**false**". it should be "**true**" only in staging.
3. Ensure, the staging related "dll" `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.dll` and `.jar` not present in the "Active" site. (This is applicable in older version of DXA, not sure in DXA 2.0)
4. Ensure, your active publication target not added with "Session Preview" settings as in "Staging".

Hope this may helps